# Troubles with GameCenter in AppStore version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

Good day to all.

I have an annoying problem with iOS GameCenter. Everything works fine in developer and AdHoc versions. But in AppStore version (I've downloaded it to my own device from AppStore) it seems, that app cannot synchronize data with GameCenter(I synchronize user achievements on application start).

Any suggestions about reasons of such kind of behavior are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "synchronize user achievements" — presumably you're authenticating a player. As per the answer below, you would get different achievements in sandbox and production.

Comment: by "synchronize user achievements" I mean that I fetch data from gameCenter about achievements, that are already done by this GameCenter player, and submit to GameCenter achievements, stored locally, that was not submitted in case of, for example, no internet connection. And as I mensioned in comment to previous answer, the troubles presents on my personal device, that is not added to developer program, so it is not possible to install AdHoc or developer build on it

Comment: I realize you can't debug, but you must be able to deduce if it's loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler: or loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: that's failing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same device you used for testing in developer mode be sure to log out of Game Center *using the Game Center app* before running your App Store app. Then when your app launches it will detect that you aren't logged in and ask you to log into Game Center. At that point you should get connected to the production Game Center.

Of course maybe you already did that, in which case I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: no, it is my own device, not for testing. it even does not included into developer's program... but thanks for your suggestion